Solana trying to unpack bonding curve
Im trying to unpack bonding curve info from Solana using the API but it I am not sure how to best unpack this data. I have this code below. Im trying to get a price for a token using the bonding curve virtual_sol_reserves, virtual_token_reserves

async def fetch_bonding_curve_reserves(bonding_curve_address, async_solana_client):
    max_retries = 6
    retry_delay = 5

    for attempt in range(max_retries):
        try:
            account_info = await async_solana_client.get_account_info(bonding_curve_address)

            if not account_info.value:
                logger.error(f"No account data available for {bonding_curve_address}")
                raise ValueError("No account data available")

            account_data = account_info.value.data

            logger.debug(f"Raw account data for {bonding_curve_address}: {account_data}")

            if isinstance(account_data, list):
                logger.debug(f"Account data is a list of length {len(account_data)}")
                if len(account_data) > 0:
                    account_data = account_data[0]
                    logger.debug(f"Using first element of the list as account data")
                else:
                    logger.error(f"Account data list is empty for {bonding_curve_address}")
                    raise ValueError("Account data list is empty")

            if isinstance(account_data, str):
                logger.debug(f"Account data is a string, converting to bytes")
                account_data = bytes(account_data, 'utf-8')

            logger.debug(f"Account data type: {type(account_data)}")
            logger.debug(f"Raw account data: {account_data}")
            logger.debug(f"Raw account data (hex): {account_data.hex()}")

            if isinstance(account_data, bytes):
                try:
                    if len(account_data) >= 16:  # Ensure there are enough bytes
                        logger.war(f"Raw account data (hex): {account_data.hex()}")
                        virtual_sol_reserves, virtual_token_reserves = struct.unpack("<QQ", account_data[:16])
                        logger.info(f"Retrieved reserves for {bonding_curve_address}:")
                        logger.info(f"  virtual_sol_reserves: {virtual_sol_reserves}")
                        logger.info(f"  virtual_token_reserves: {virtual_token_reserves}")

                        # Sanity check on the values
                        if virtual_sol_reserves > 1e18 or virtual_token_reserves > 1e18:
                            logger.warning("Unpacked values are unusually high, please verify the account data structure.")
                            raise ValueError("Unpacked values are unusually high")

                        sol_price_usd = await fetch_current_sol_price_in_usd()
                        token_price_sol = get_price_from_reserves(virtual_sol_reserves, virtual_token_reserves)
                        token_price_usd = token_price_sol * sol_price_usd if sol_price_usd is not None else None
                        return virtual_sol_reserves, virtual_token_reserves, token_price_sol, token_price_usd
                    else:
                        logger.error(f"Account data length is insufficient for unpacking: {len(account_data)} bytes")
                        raise ValueError("Account data length is insufficient for unpacking")
                except struct.error as e:
                    logger.error(f"Failed to unpack account data for {bonding_curve_address}: {e}")
                    raise ValueError("Failed to unpack account data")
            else:
                logger.error(f"Unexpected data type for account data: {type(account_data)}")
                raise TypeError("Unexpected data type for account data")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} failed for {bonding_curve_address}: {e}")
            if attempt < max_retries - 1:
                await asyncio.sleep(retry_delay)
            else:
                return None, None, None, None

    return None, None, None, None

additional function
def get_price_from_reserves(virtual_sol_reserves, virtual_token_reserves):
    try:
        if virtual_token_reserves == 0:
            logger.warning("Virtual token reserves are zero. Returning price as 0.")
            return Decimal(0)

        logger.debug(f"Calculating price from reserves: virtual_sol_reserves={virtual_sol_reserves}, virtual_token_reserves={virtual_token_reserves}")

        token_price = Decimal(virtual_sol_reserves) / Decimal(virtual_token_reserves)
        logger.info(f"Token price (before conversion): {token_price}")

        token_price_sol = token_price / Decimal(LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
        logger.info(f"Token price (in SOL): {token_price_sol}")

        return token_price_sol

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error calculating price from reserves: {e}")
        return None

Then we try to calculate token price

async def calculate_token_price(bonding_curve_address, async_solana_client):
    sol_reserves, token_reserves = await fetch_bonding_curve_reserves(bonding_curve_address, async_solana_client)
    if sol_reserves is None or token_reserves is None:
        return None, None

    sol_price_usd = await fetch_current_sol_price_in_usd()
    if sol_price_usd is None:
        return None, None

    token_price_sol = sol_reserves / token_reserves
    token_price_usd = token_price_sol * sol_price_usd
    return token_price_sol.quantize(Decimal('.000000000000000001')), token_price_usd.quantize(Decimal('.000000000000000001'))

Ive had different values twice in terms of the size of the number, but I think the main issue here is how the data is being unpacked wrong so I cant get the correct token price my logs  HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

2024-05-21 02:27:33,465 - Attempt 6: SOL reserves:
6966180631402821399, Token reserves: 1005937500000001
2024-05-21 02:27:33,465 - Unusually high values detected, attempt
{attempt+1}

Thanks for your help in advance. Been on this for far too long
Im expecting to get get correct values for virtual_sol_reserves, virtual_token_reserves

I haven't dived into the code, but the resulting "6966180631402821399" is something stored in the first 8 bytes of account data (i'm trying to understand what it is actually is), and you need to use byte 8 to 49 to get virtual token reserves, virtual sol reserves , ... , token supply and completion status respectively.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
